# Dates not importing to SQL database correctly from Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have the following (subset of a) Pandas dataframe that I am trying to upload to a MySQL database:
[image]

Here are details of the data using the info() function:

[image]

For added context, I previously converted both the `tourn_date` and `date` column to a datetime format using this code:

```
pd.to_datetime(all_data['tourn_date']).dt.date
```

Finally, here is the code that I'm using to import the data into the MySQL database:

```
for index, row in all_data.iterrows():
    inserts = [row.tourn_id, row.year, row.round_num, row.tourn_date, row.date]

    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO AllPlayerStats 
                    (TourneyID, Year, RoundNum, TourneyDate, TDate)
                    values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", inserts)
db.commit()
cursor.close()
```

However, when I run this, some of the dates (like the ones shown above), are appearing as NULL in the database (see below) despite other tournaments working just fine and the format of the `TourneyDate` and `Date` columns in the database being of date type. In some instances, the `tourn_date` uploads correctly but the `date` doesn't.

[image]

Is there a way to troubleshoot this and understand why this is occurring? I'm very confused as to what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is claiming the dates are datatype Object, you will need them to be Cast as a Date type first.  Information about how to Cast as a Date found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp

Also, make sure that the MySQL column you are inserting into has the correct data type format as well.  Most problems that make no sense are usually data type issues, all too easy to compare x = 1 to y = "1" and not understand why x is NOT = to y for example.

UPDATE - a second answer appeared, the concepts are the same, I guess the difference is if you want to do it with Python or with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Consider either converting your date values to [**`StringDtype`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#text-data-types) (not `object`) or to `datetime64` without the `dt.date` attribute. MySQL may map Python datetimes to its `date` type (i.e., minus time component). Consider also `executemany` from `DataFrame.to_numpy()`.

Do note: `astype("string")` renders the `StringDtype` and is different than `astype(str)` or `astype("str")` which render `object` type.

```py
sql = """INSERT INTO AllPlayerStats (TourneyID, Year, RoundNum, TourneyDate, TDate)
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

# StringDtype
all_data["tourn_date"], all_data["date"] = (
    all_data["tourn_date"].astype("string"), 
    all_data["date"].astype("string")
)

# datetime
all_data["tourn_date"], all_data["date"] = (
    pd.to_datetime(all_data["tourn_date"]), 
    pd.to_datetime(all_data["date"])
)

vals = all_data[["tourn_id", "year", "round_num", "tourn_date", "date"]].to_numpy()

cursor.executemany(sql, vals) 
db.commit() 
cursor.close()
```